# Modify numbers in large string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I'm trying to modify certain numbers inside a large string, which start with an #.

So for example I have this String:

```
var text = "#41 = AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D ( 'NONE', #3200, #1543, #6232 ) ;
#42 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE', #180, #933, #1234, .T. ) ;"
```

Then I want to add a fixed number to every number after an "#" e.g. add 100 to every number to get this:

```
text = "#141 = AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D ( 'NONE', #3300, #1643, #6332 ) ;
#142 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE', #280, #1033, #1334, .T. ) ;"
```

I got this far with regex:

```
const offset = 100;
const matchingExpression = /\#(\d+)/ig;
text = text.replaceAll(matchingExpression, "#" + //old value + offset);
```

I now can replace all numbers that start with an "#". But how do I get the old values?

I'm not very familiar with regex and don't know if this approach is the way to go.
Hope you can help me.

Thanks in regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second argument (function callback) of the [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```js
const add100 = (text) => text.replace(/#(\d+)/gm, (m, n) => `#${+n + 100}`);


const text = `#41 = AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D ( 'NONE', #3200, #1543, #6232 ) ;
#42 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE', #180, #933, #1234, .T. ) ;`;

console.log(add100(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like this:

```
const offset = 100;
const matchingExpression = /\#(\d+)/ig;

text = text.replace(matchingExpression, function(match) {
    return "#" + (parseInt(match.slice(1)) + offset)
});
```

Comment: Why the `i` insensitive?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I merely copied OP's code/regex because OP's question was how to get the value that is being replaced, not what the correct RegEx would be.